# Console windows closes right after I hit ctrl+F5 in visual studio tools for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, ptvs

I have installed Python Tools for Visual Studio and I cannot see the output in the console window like I see output when I run a C# console application within visual studio upon hitting the following Shortcut keys.

**F5  --**  Starts debugging the program and closes the console window in c# and in Python
**Ctrl+F5 --** Start without debugging, works as expected in C# **but not in Python program**. It always exits the console window under both the options.

There is a third option "**Execute Project in Python Interactive**" for a Python Application.  This option sometimes produces output and sometimes does not.

What should I do to see the output in the console window and the windows should not close after running the program?  Is this even possible or some conceptual difference for python console apps?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an option in Tools->Options->Python Tools->Advanced under the Debugging section for "Wait for input when process exits abnormally" and "Wait for input when the process exits normally".  I thought they were supposed to be on by default but enabling them should cause it to wait.

Answer (score 2):

for future visitors from google. This doesn't involve Python settings, but to prevent the console window from closing automatically while using "Start without debugging" (Ctrl + F5).  Try looking for this setting.

`Project -> "project name" Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System`
Then look for the `SubSystem` property, and set it to
`Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` 
You can select it via drop down or try and type it.
if you have trouble seeing it under `System` you can also check under `All Options`

Hit save and then it should work immediately.  Confirmed this works on VisualStudio 2013, but I also think it works on other versions too.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: Visual Studio 2017 - the items listed have moved :-( and I don't know where they moved to