# python visual studio- output just flashes for a second

Tags: python, visual-studio, ide

I installed the python tools for visual studio from http://pytools.codeplex.com/. I find that when I press f5 or ctrl+f5 the output in command prompt just flashes for a second and I am not able to see clearly. Is there any settings that I have to change? I would prefer the output in a python IDLE rather than the command prompt is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: You could add a raw_input() at the end to wait for you to press enter.

Comment: There is an option for that. See [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424873/console-windows-closes-right-after-i-hit-ctrlf5-in-visual-studio-tools-for-pyth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw_input() at the end works.